# div flex stretch not applying and doesn't change height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Notice the div is set to `display: flex`. It has some tables inside it. I can't change the height of the div to take 85% of the page without the tables stretching out evenly inside the pink div.

I'm trying to spread the tables' contents evenly inside the div. I can't find the right rule-set to make it work. I don't know where to change the content class or the `.foodiv` class.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    display: flex;
}

.foodiv {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 4;
    flex-basis:   auto;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-self: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    margin: 10px;  
}


.content {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="food.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="foodiv">
    <center>
        <table id="t" style="color:white">
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="pizza.html"><button>Pizza</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="pasta.html"><button>Pasta</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="burger.html"><button>Burger</button></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="noodles.html"><button>Noodles</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="hs.html"><button>Chinese Hot and Sour
                            Soup</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="cgs.html"><button>Carrot Ginger Soup</button></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="breadroll.html"><button>Bread Roll</button></a>
                </td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ps.html"><button>Paneer Sandwich</button></a>
                </td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="vegetablemaggie.html"><button>Vegetable
                            Maggie</button></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="frenchtoast.html"><button>French
                            Toast</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="tacos.html"><button>Tacos</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="momos.html"><button>Momos</button></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="pt.html"><button>Paneer Tikka</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ccb.html"><button>Crispy Chilly
                            Babycorn</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="ac.html"><button>American Chopsuey</button></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="q.html"><button>Quesadilla</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="chococake.html"><button>Chocolate
                            Cake</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="lbp.html"><button>Lemon Bar Peeps</button></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="sbpie.html"><button>Strawberry Pie</button></a>
                </td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="tiramisu.html"><button>Tiramisu</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="pc.html"><button>Panna Cotta</button></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="bmc.html"><button>Blueberry Muffin
                            Cake</button></a></td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="cheesecake.html"><button>Cheesecake</button></a>
                </td>
                <td class="content"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="cm.html"><button>Chocolate Milkshake</button></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *only*  child of your flex container `.foodiv` is the `<center>` tag - one flex child can stretch, but the element in there (the "grandchildren")  won't be affected by that flex setting.  Erase the `<center>` tag  and center the tables with another method.

Answer (score 0):

there was some problems with you code. replace you HTML & CSS with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="food.css" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .foodiv {
        background-color: lightcoral;
        height: 85vh;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 30px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: stretch;
      }

      #t {
        display: flex;
      }

      tbody {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      button {
        padding: 5px 15px;
      }

      tr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foodiv">
      <table id="t" style="color: white;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="pizza.html"
                ><button>Pizza</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="pasta.html"
                ><button>Pasta</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="burger.html"
                ><button>Burger</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="noodles.html"
                ><button>Noodles</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="hs.html"
                ><button>Chinese Hot and Sour Soup</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="cgs.html"
                ><button>Carrot Ginger Soup</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="breadroll.html"
                ><button>Bread Roll</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="ps.html"
                ><button>Paneer Sandwich</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="vegetablemaggie.html"
                ><button>Vegetable Maggie</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="frenchtoast.html"
                ><button>French Toast</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="tacos.html"
                ><button>Tacos</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="momos.html"
                ><button>Momos</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="pt.html"
                ><button>Paneer Tikka</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="ccb.html"
                ><button>Crispy Chilly Babycorn</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="ac.html"
                ><button>American Chopsuey</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="q.html"
                ><button>Quesadilla</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="chococake.html"
                ><button>Chocolate Cake</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="lbp.html"
                ><button>Lemon Bar Peeps</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="sbpie.html"
                ><button>Strawberry Pie</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="tiramisu.html"
                ><button>Tiramisu</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="pc.html"
                ><button>Panna Cotta</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="bmc.html"
                ><button>Blueberry Muffin Cake</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="cheesecake.html"
                ><button>Cheesecake</button></a
              >
            </td>
            <td class="content">
              <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="cm.html"
                ><button>Chocolate Milkshake</button></a
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello the code you give its good but it didn't do what i want i want the buttons or the table to starch evenly inside the div i have been modifying your code but nothing happen i give every class a different background color to understand more but they just change is something wrong with the build in table and just make them buttons

Comment: I could have helped if you would have described your problem in a better way. or just put a image of your expected result. It's hard to understand what type of result one is expecting. So always describe the problem in a better way so that people can get a clear perspective of what you are looking for. Thank you.